# Rendering drop-down boxes for country and region

Tags: php, form

In PHP how can I follow the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle in this piece of code? The 2 classes in question share an awful lot of code.

```
<?php

interface iSelect
{
    public static function display();
}


class CountrySelect implements iSelect {

    static $template = 'select_template.php';

    public static function display() {

        if ( class_exists( 'View' ) ) {

            // Get the full path to the template file.

            $templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . static::$template;

            $viewData = array(
                "options" => '_countries',
                "optionsText" => 'name',
                "optionsValue" => 'geonameId',
                "value" => 'selectedCountry',
                "caption" => 'Country'
            );

            // Return the rendered HTML
            return View::render( $templatePath, $viewData );

        }
        else {
            return "You are trying to render a template, but we can't find the View Class";
        }
    }
}

class RegionSelect implements iSelect {

    static $template = 'select_template.php';

    public static function display() {

        if ( class_exists( 'View' ) ) {

            // Get the full path to the template file.

            $templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . static::$template;

            $viewData = array(
                "options" => '_regions',
                "optionsText" => 'name',
                "optionsValue" => 'name',
                "value" => 'selectedCity',
                "caption" => 'Region'
            );

            // Return the rendered HTML
            return View::render( $templatePath, $viewData );

        }
        else {
            return "You are trying to render a template, but we can't find the View Class";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

The code in question is for php templating. Here is the template:

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <div class="select">
        <span class="arr"></span>
        <select data-bind="options: <? echo $options ?>,
            optionsText: '<? echo $optionsText ?>',
            optionsValue: '<? echo $optionsValue ?>',
            value: <? echo $value ?>,
            optionsCaption: '<? echo $caption ?>'">
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the View.php which takes the `$ViewData` and the `$template` file and then renders it:

```
<?php

/** View.php **/

class View {

    /**
     * -------------------------------------
     * Render a Template.
     * -------------------------------------
     * 
     * @param $filePath - include path to the template.
     * @param null $viewData - any data to be used within the template.
     * @return string - 
     * 
     */
    public static function render( $filePath, $viewData = null ) {

        // Was any data sent through?
        ( $viewData ) ? extract( $viewData ) : null;

        ob_start();
        include ( $filePath );
        $template = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();

        return $template;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In PHP how can I follow the DRY (don't repeat yourself) principle in this piece of code? The 2 classes in question share an awful lot of code.

One approach would be to create a common superclass and extract the common elements of the function. As everything except the `viewData` is the same, just pass that to the newly created common function:

```
<?php
interface iSelect {
    public static function display();
}

abstract class AreaSelect implements iSelect {
    public static function displayData($viewData) {
            if ( class_exists( 'View' ) ) {

                // Get the full path to the template file.

                $templatePath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/' . static::$template;

                // Return the rendered HTML
                return View::render( $templatePath, $viewData );

            }
            else {
                return "You are trying to render a template, but we can't find the View Class";
            }
    }
}

class CountrySelect extends AreaSelect {
    public static function display() {
        $viewData = array(
            "options" => '_countries',
            "optionsText" => 'name',
            "optionsValue" => 'geonameId',
            "value" => 'selectedCountry',
            "caption" => 'Country'
        );
        parent::displayData($viewData);
    }
}

class RegionSelect extends AreaSelect {
    public static function display() {
        $viewData = array(
            "options" => '_regions',
            "optionsText" => 'name',
            "optionsValue" => 'name',
            "value" => 'selectedCity',
            "caption" => 'Region'
        );
        parent::displayData($viewData);
    }
}
```

The `displayData` is now so generic, that it might make sense to create a `AbstractSelect` class instead of an `AreaSelect` as it is likely that other selects will use the exact same method as well.

**Extract**

You should always be careful when using extract like this. If you ever have an entry that is called `filePath`, you would overwrite the `$filePath` argument and thus break your code.

Additionally, if `$viewData` is ever user-controlled, you would have an LFI vulnerability. It's unlikely, but I would always try to make generic methods such as this as secure as possible (the calling code is unlikely to expect a security issue), even for unlikely use (that's also why I would probably check `filePath` for directory traversal, just in case, as well as html-encode all variables in the template); at the very minimum, I would document the issue.

**Misc**

- why are you checking if `View` exists (it should always exist, right?), but not if `$template` exists (it's more likely that one of many templates gets misplaced than that the single view class gets lost)?
- your placement of curly brakets is not consistent.
- your comments aren't really needed. Stuff like `// Return the rendered HTML` is already clear from the code. It would be better to remove comments such as these, and add PHPDoc style comments documenting the methods behaviour instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have two same classes? You can make parent abstract class instead of interface and move all logic to parent.